# Trying to print a PHP mysql row with jquery .load into a div based on specific input into a form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, function, pdo

I know the title is a bit long, here's what I am trying to do. 
I have a div with the class `.draggable2`, I am trying to load a page named `productLookup.php` into it when the user submits a form. The form takes the "product name" then checks it in the database and returns certain information on that product. However, I am awfully confused as to where exactly my problem is, I don't know if I am not calling the function where `.load()` is correctly, or if I am not inputting the value into my `productLookup.php` page.

Here are the full details:

I have a **script** tag right after `<body>`, in it I have the declaration of:

```
function getR(id) {
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.draggable2').load('productLookup.php?valueName=' + id);
  });
}
```

Then right after it, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submitProduct').click(function() {
   var valueR = $('#nameValue').val();
   getR(valueR);
   });
});
```

Here I am declaring a function that will load `productLookup.php` with a value of whatever is inputted into the form before the button is clicked. I am new to these languages when it comes to this so I understand I may be wrong. The button has an ID of `#submitProduct`, the input area has an ID of `nameValue`. If I am correct, the `.click()` is supposed to call the getR function. So, why is it not working?

Here is the form I am using:

```
<form method = "POST">
<p>Product name: <input type="text" name="valueName" id = "nameValue" /></p>
<p><button type="submit" id = "submitProduct" >Input</button></p>
</form>
```

Now, here is my `productLookup.php` page:

```
<?php 

    $user = 'xxxx';
    $pass = 'xxxx';
    $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $user, $pass );

    $productName = $_POST['valueName'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE :valueName ";
    $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $query->execute(array(':valueName'=>$productName));
    $info = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $theName = $info->name;
    print $theName;

 ?>
```

Please help me if you can, I am extremely confused as to what I am doing wrong, everything seems right. It's not making any sense to me why the value is not being inputted. 
Another thing that leads me to believe that perhaps the error is in my `productLookup.php` is that when I input the url manually myself, for example: `mywebsite.com/productLookup.php?valueName=ProductName` it shows a blank page, technically it should show the info I am printing right?

Comment: You don't need `$(document).ready()` in the `getR()` function. That's used for specifying actions you want to happen immediately when the DOM is ready, it's not needed later.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure at first if it was a problem or not, I've tried it without the `$(document).ready()` and it's still blank. :(

Comment: I said you don't _need_ it, I didn't say it would cause a problem. I wasn't proposing that as a solution, it was just a comment.

Comment: Oh, I see, for that I thank you Barmar!

Comment: Don't change the question to match the answer. How will future readers understand why I wrote that in my answer, when the question no longer has the bug?

Comment: You're talking about the `$_POST` to `$_GET` right? I will undo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load()` uses a `GET` query, not `POST`. So change:

```
$productName = $_POST['valueName'];
```

to:

```
$productName = $_GET['valueName'];
```

Also, you need to prevent normal submission of the form. Use `preventDefault()` in the click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitProduct').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var valueR = $('#nameValue').val();
        getR(valueR);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed, the `<form method = "GET">` and I also changed to `$productName = $_GET['valueName'];`... it still did not solve the issue, **however** now whenever I input a product, the url of the page im on has `?valueName=ProductName` could I be that it is accidently calling it on the homepage?

Comment: Okay, here is an update, after doing what you said, If I enter the URL manually: `productLookup.php?valueName=ProductName` it prints the product name as it's supposed to, the problem is trying to load it into that div, it's still not doing it.

Comment: IT WORKED. Thank you so much Barmar. It was the `e.preventDefault();` that did the trick, do you mind explaining why that was causing it to print nothing?

Comment: Because you're submitting the form, which reloads the page from scratch.

Comment: But doesn't it only submit the form when the button is clicked?

Comment: Pressing Return in the last text field of a form is equivalent to clicking on the submit button.

Comment: @Barmar You should add a return false, because Firefox doesn't handle preventDefault

Comment: Okay, I see, that is why I was also getting a `form resubmission` right. Once again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @pc-shooter Can you provide evidence of that? I googled for it, and found some SO questions that claimed it didn't work, but they were because the OP had some other problem in their code. Why would it be documented in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) if it wasn't supported?

Comment: @Barmar I know that MDN sais, it works and I've only a recent example: http://www.gewerbe-bischofszell.ch.antiqua.sui-inter.net/mitglieder.html  Run the code from: /assets/js/membermap.js line 132 & 148 with preventDefault. It works in chrome but not in FF. If you have an explanaition for this I'd be glad to learn...

Comment: @Barmar You were right! The example I gave you had problems elsewhere! The preventDefault works also in FF